# Using Processing to Create Arcade of Games, after game is chosen. Won't draw, still runs. processing

Tags: java, drawing, processing

Hi basically whenever I click <kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>b</kbd> to run one of my games they run, but you can't see them as they don't draw over the main menu screen. These games do work if separated.

```java
PImage pongImage, brickImage;
boolean mouseDown = false;

boolean [] keys = new boolean [128];
Ball ball;
Paddleb gamerPaddle;
static ArrayList<Brick> bricks = new ArrayList();

Puck puck;
Paddle one;//left
Paddle two;//right

int oneScore = 0;
int twoScore = 0;

int gameScreen = 0;
void setup() {
    fullScreen();

    ball = new Ball();//creating objects
    gamerPaddle = new Paddleb();
    puck = new Puck();//creating objects
    one = new Paddle(true);
    two = new Paddle(false);
}

void draw() {
    menuPress();
    if (gameScreen == 0) {
        mainMenu();
    }
    if (gameScreen ==1) {
        gamePong();
    }
    if (gameScreen == 2) {
        gameBrick();
    }
}

void keyReleased() {
    keys[key] = false;
    one.move(0);
    two.move(0);
    gamerPaddle.move(0);
}

void menuPress() {
    if (keys['p'] == true) {
        gameScreen = 1;
    } else if (keys ['b'] == true) {
        gameScreen =2;
    } else {
        gameScreen = 0;
    }
}

void moves() {
    if (keys['w'] == true) {
       one.move(-10);
    } else if (keys['s'] == true) {
       one.move(10);
    }
    if (keys['i'] == true) {
        two.move(-10);
    } else if (keys['k'] == true) {
        two.move(10);
    }
    if (keys['a'] == true) {
        gamerPaddle.move(-10);
    } else if (keys['d'] == true) {
        gamerPaddle.move(10);
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
    keys[key] = true;
}

void drawBricks() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= bricks.size() - 1; i++) {
        fill(255);
        rectMode(CORNER);
        rect(bricks.get(i).x, bricks.get(i).y, bricks.get(i).s, bricks.get(i).s2);
    }
}

void bricksSetup() {

    rectMode(CORNER);
    float s = 80;
    float x = width/4;
    float y = Brick.space;
    while (y < height/2) {
        while (x < width - width/4) {
            bricks.add(new Brick(x, y, s, s));
            x +=90;
        }
        x = width/4;
        y +=90;
    }
}

void mainMenu() {
    float picsY = height/2;
    float brickX = 2 * width/3;
    float pongX = width/3 - width/4;

    pongImage = loadImage("pong photo.PNG");
    brickImage = loadImage("Brick breaker.PNG");
    pongImage.resize(width/4, height/4);
    brickImage.resize(width/4, height/4);
    background(150);
    fill(255);
    textSize(72);
    text("AhMen's Arcade", width/5 + width/7, height/3);

    image(pongImage, pongX, picsY);
    text("Pong", width/6, 4 * height/5 + height/50);
    image(brickImage, brickX, picsY);
    text("Brick Breaker", 2 * width/3 + width/100, 4 * height/5 + height/50);
}

void gamePong() {
    background(0);
    System.out.println("cat");
    boolean gameEnding = false;
    do {
        background(0);
        one.screen();//creates paddle
        two.screen();
        puck.position();
        puck.sides();
        puck.screen();

        moves();

        puck.checkHitOne(one);
        puck.checkHitTwo(two);

        one.refresh();//limits y movement and keeps it moving at speed of 0 to make stops and starts not noticible
        two.refresh();

        fill(255);
        textSize(32);
        text(oneScore, 20, 50);
        text(twoScore, width-40, 50);
        textMode(CENTER);
        text("PONG", width/2-55, 50);
    } while (gameEnding != true);
    exit();
}

void gameBrick() {
    System.out.println("ya");
    background(0);
    bricksSetup();
    ball.position();
    while (ball.y - ball.r > height || ball.p1Score >= ((bricks.size()-1)*50)) {
        System.out.println('l');
        background(0);
        moves();

        drawBricks();
        ball.checkHitTwo(gamerPaddle);
        ball.checkHitBrick();

        gamerPaddle.screen();//creates paddle
        gamerPaddle.refresh();//limits y movement and keeps it moving at speed of 0 to make stops and starts not noticible
        gamerPaddle.refresh();

        ball.position();
        ball.sides();
        ball.screen();
        ball.score();
    }
    exit();
}
```

this is just the main method btw, I do have other methods for the objects. I am not sure why this doesn't work, but if someone that has an Idea what the issue may be please lmk.

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your issue? Note, if an answer to your question has solved your issue completely, then you should accept the answer. (check mark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

The processing draw function does not run on a seperate thread. When you have a while loop, which doesn't end, the draw-function never gets executed anymore.

You have to use variables scoped to the processing file and not just a function and then modify those variables inside the functions you currently use as the game-loops.

For example, if you want a program where a ball moves to the right and returns to coordinate 0 after passing it, you would have to structure it like this:

```
Ball ball = new Ball();

void draw() {
    playBallGame();
    drawBall();
}

void playBallGame() {
    if (ball.x > width) ball.x = 0;
    ball.x++;
}
```

Not like this:

```
void draw() {
    drawBall();
    playBallGame();
}

void playBallGame() {
    Ball ball = new Ball();
    while (true) {
        if (ball.x > width) ball.x = 0;
        ball.x++;
    }
}
```